# How to install standalone gpgv signature verification tool

Tags: yum, gpg

How do I install [gpgv](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gpgv.1.html), the stripped-down version of `gpg` (and one of the [helper tools](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Helper-Tools.html#Helper-Tools))? I'm looking for a solution that I can use on [Photon OS](https://github.com/vmware/photon) containers, without installing the full `gpg`.

I know that on Ubuntu it can be done with `sudo apt install gpgv2` which I see only takes "**52.2 kB** of additional disk space".

Photon OS uses `yum`, so I tried:

```
# yum install gpgv2
gpgv2 package not found or not installed
Error(1011) : No matching packages

# yum install gpgv
gpgv package not found or not installed
Error(1011) : No matching packages

# yum search gpgv
Error(1599) : No matches found

# yum search gpg
photon-repos : Photon repo files, gpg keys
password-store : A secure password manager for unix systems.
photon-repos : Photon repo files, gpg keys
gnupg : OpenPGP standard implementation used for encrypted communication and data storage.
gpgme : High-Level Crypto API
gpgme-devel : Static libraries and header files from GPGME, GnuPG Made Easy.
libgpg-error : libgpg-error
libgpg-error-devel : Libraries and header files for libgpg-error
libgpg-error-lang : Additional language files for libgpg-error
tdnf-plugin-repogpgcheck : tdnf plugin providign gpg verification for repository metadata
gnupg : OpenPGP standard implementation used for encrypted communication and data storage.
gpgme : High-Level Crypto API
gpgme-devel : Static libraries and header files from GPGME, GnuPG Made Easy.
libassuan-devel : GnuPG IPC library
password-store : A secure password manager for unix systems.
photon-repos : Photon repo files, gpg keys
tdnf-plugin-repogpgcheck : tdnf plugin providign gpg verification for repository metadata
```

Eventually I settled with `yum install gnupg` which does provide `gpgv` but it comes at a cost of **11.80M**. Is there a manual or alternative way of getting *only* `gpgv`? That's all I need in the container, because it's required for signature verification. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want using a multi-stage Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/photon:latest AS builder

RUN yum -y install gnupg

FROM docker.io/photon:latest

COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/gpgv /usr/bin
COPY --from=builder /lib64/libgcrypt.so.20 /lib64/libgcrypt-error.so.0 /lib64/
```

But unless you are running in an extremely resource constrained environment, I would install the `gnupg` package and leave it at that (or switch base distributions to something that does package `gpgv` separately).

Comment: That's a good enough option, thanks for the idea. Had to use `COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.20 /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/lib/` instead.